# Best way to convert a Java Map to a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, ikvm

I need to write a function in C# that takes in a java.util.Map and converts it to a C# Dictionary.  (The project I'm working on uses [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to use some Java classes in C#.)

I've tried using a foreach loop (e.g. `foreach (java.util.Map.Entry in map)` or `foreach (string key in map.keySet())` to add to the Dictionary element-by-element, but it seems that Java Maps and Sets are not enumerable.

What's my best approach here?  Should I use a java.util.Iterator?  (I'm not opposed to using a Java Iterator on principle, but it feels like there should be a cleaner, more "c-sharp-y" way.)  I guess I could get the keySet, use the Set method toArray(), and iterate through *that*, but again, it doesn't feel "c-sharp-y".  Should I just get over myself and do one of those things, or is there a better way?  (Or, of those two options, which is more efficient in terms of time/space taken?)

For reference, here's a sketch of what I'm trying to do:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> convertMap(java.util.Map map)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (String key in map.keySet()) // doesn't work; map is not enumerable
        dict.Add(key, map.get(key));
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: How can you mix Java and C#?

Comment: @jsalonen by [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)

Comment: Oh right, good point.  I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @Jsalonen `How can you mix Java and C#?` - That's more an ethic question than a technical question. Technically, you 'could', say mix swiss chocolate and mud and eat it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an extension method for `map to Dictionary`

```
java.util.Map map = new java.util.HashMap();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", 2);

var dict = map.ToDictionary<string, int>();
```

---

```
public static class JavaUtils
{
    public static Dictionary<K, V> ToDictionary<K, V>(this java.util.Map map)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<K, V>();
        var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            var key = (K)iterator.next();
            dict.Add(key, (V)map.get(key));
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got one horrible suggestion which *might* work. Introduce an extension method on `Iterable` (or `Iterable<E>` if you can, but I'm assuming generics don't really work...)

```
public static class JavaExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable ToEnumerable(Iterable iterable)
    {
        var iterator = iterable.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            yield return iterator.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> convertMap(java.util.Map map)
{
    return map.keySet()
              .ToEnumerable()
              .Cast<string>()
              .ToDictionary(key => key, key => map.get(key));
}
```

I'm not sure whether that's nice or utterly foul... but obviously the `ToEnumerable` method is very reusable.

Comment: Interesting topic (off-topic here) is.. how do fake java generics play together with real .Net generics using IKVM? have you ever experimented with that?

Comment: @HighCore: Nope, not at all.

Comment: It certainly works, though I ended up doing a different solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @firechant Which one did you use in the end? Because there cannot be any solution more elegant than Jon Skeet's LINQ approach.